# Using Bluestacks with VLC and Live Net TV

Tags: android

When I tried to open the app on PC I got a security login from google on my Samsung phone that a new OnePlus 5 device had logged in to my account.I do not have such a device so I changed my password on google.Any ideas to what it was?

Comment: And was the IP outside of your area?

Answer (score 1):

Bluestacks is an Android emulator. When you run it, it pretends to be a particular Android based device. For the newest version of Bluestacks, I believe **OnePlus 5** is the default device emulated.

So yes, you do have a **OnePlus 5** device, it's just emulated.